# Rangy range contained within a jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, rangy

I'm working on a JavaScript wrapper around the [Rangy JavaScript plugin](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/). What I'm trying to do: given a jQuery selector and a range, detect if the range is contained within the selector. This is for a space where a user will read a document and be able to make comments about particular sections. So I have a div with `id="viewer"` that contains the document, and I have an area of buttons that do things after a user selects some text. Here is the (broken) function:

```
function selectedRangeInRegion(selector) {
    var selectionArea = $(selector);
    var range = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var inArea = (selectionArea.has(range.startContainer).length > 0);

    if (inArea) {
        return range;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It appears that `selectionArea.has(range.startContainer)` returns an array of size 0. I have tried wrapping like: `$(range.startContainer)`. Any tips?

---

I developed a solution for this problem. This assumes you have a div selector and that your content does not have any divs:

```
function containsLegalRange(selector, range) {
  var foundContainingNode = false;

  var container = range.commonAncestorContainer

  var nearestDiv = $(container).closest("div");    
  if (nearestDiv.attr("id") == selector) {
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a typo (missing brace) in the original code. I'd assume that this is not intentional?

Comment: Yes, it was not intentional. I removed the debugging code from the code I pasted in instead of removing it beforehand. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `has()` works: the parameter you pass to it is either a selector string or a DOM element, whereas `range.startContainer` is a DOM node that may in practice be a text node or an element.

I don't think there will be a way that's as easy as you're hoping. The following is as simple as I can think of off the top of my head.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRVCm/

Code:

```
function containsRange(selector, range, allowPartiallySelected) {
    var foundContainingNode = false;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        if (range.containsNode(this, allowPartiallySelected)) {
            foundContainingNode = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return foundContainingNode;
}
```

Comment: This appears to almost work, but if I select some text in the chosen div and some outside that div, containsRange returns true. Changing "allowPartiallySelected" to false, containsRange seems to always return false. Is there any way to turn a jquery selector into a range and call containsNode on that?

Comment: @Jordan: There no way in general to create a single range that contains the contents of a jQuery object because jQuery objects contain a set of possibly disjoint nodes. You could create a range that contained every node in the jQUery object but it wouldn't be helpful since it may also contain nodes that are not part of the jQuery object. Regarding the the `allowPartiallySelected` set to `false`, I sympathise: it's because `containsNode` is pedantic in what it consider "containing", which is problem because a single visual location could be any one of several different points in the DOM.

Comment: @Jordan: For example, if the cursor is at the start of the main div, it's considered to be at the start of the text node within the div, but the range for the main div starts immediately before the div. `containsNode()` is a non-standard Rangy extension but is consistent with other, standard Range methods, but is not that easy to deal with for most use cases, so I'm considering adding a `containsNodeText()` or similar method to Rangy ranges.

Comment: Tim, thank you very much for your help (pretty cool the developer of the plugin I'm using answered my question). I came up with a different solution and edited my original question.

Comment: @Jordan: Fair enough. I was trying to answer the most general case, but if your needs are simpler then that's great.

Answer (score 0):

.has() can be weird sometimes and produce `.length == 0` when it is not supposed to. Try this way instead:

```
function selectedRangeInRegion(selector) {
  var range = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectionArea = selector + ':has(\'' + range.startContainer + '\')';
  var inArea = $(selectionArea).length > 0);
  if (inArea) {
    return range; 
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please click the checkmark beside my answer if this helped you!

Comment: That's unlikely to work in all cases: `range.startContainer` could in practice be either a text node or an element, so in the latter case converting it to a string definitely won't help.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I get the error "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Text]" which occurs when calling $(selectionArea).